# is it possible to make an animation of a perfect circle beginning with an SVG line

Tags: html, css, svg

Is it possible to make an animation of a perfect circle beginning with an SVG line, which will widen from the center of the line and become a circle?

I've been browsing about it, but it doesn't suit my expectations. Either because the keywords I use are wrong or something else.

I have this for my line:

```
<svg height="210" width="500">
  <line x1="150" y1="150" x2="50" y2="150" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0); stroke-width:2" />
</svg>
```

… and the process I'm looking for will be like this:

[image: process steps]

Comment: How do you want the animation to occur? On mouse hover? On page load? We need a little more information.

Comment: Start with a circle, clip it with a rectangle, animate the rectangle's height and y to expand the clip and reveal the circle.

Comment: @disinfor on page load the line opacity will change from 0 to 1 and the line become a circle

Comment: @RobertLongson i'm not that good with css but i will try it .... 
your advice is quite clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with pure CSS:

```css
.box {
  width:200px;
  height:4px;
  background:radial-gradient(circle,#000 99px,transparent 100px);
    
  animation:toCircle 5s linear 1s forwards;
}
@keyframes toCircle{
  to{
    height:200px;
  }
}


body {
  margin:0;
  height:100vh;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Comment: am i have to add a height on my divs ?? 
I just tried adding width on my div without height..

Comment: @BunchOfPaper yes, you have to add height since the trick is all about animating the height

Comment: is it right when I don't add my own div height, the div has an automatic height?

Comment: @BunchOfPaper I don't think, because you will not be able to animate the height unless you consider another trick where you can animat the height of a wrapper of your div

Comment: i have several question .... why i cant use height under 4px ?? it just look like a box here and i want it like a line , and how to increase the size of the circle ?? i try to put 500px in width but the size is always the same as 200px

Comment: @BunchOfPaper you need to also adjust the valie of the gradient. I have defined a circle with 100px radius, so if you increase the width you need to also increase the radius

Comment: i do but it just like a half circle from center

Comment: @BunchOfPaper you need to also increase the height: https://jsfiddle.net/0o7nb8xr/ for a circle with 200px radius we need at least 400px height

Comment: ohh okay , one more thing .... in jsfiddle the div start with just like a single line ..... but in my sublime text ... the same code , the same div but start like a rectangle ... i dont know you understand my question though :D

Answer (score 0):

You can elegantly transform an SVG ellipse from a line to a circle:

```css
svg {
  background-color: #fff;
}

ellipse {
  background:radial-gradient(circle,#000 99px,transparent 100px);
  animation:toCircle 1s linear 1s forwards;
}

@keyframes toCircle{
  to {
    ry:50;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg width="700" height="500">
 <ellipse cx="100" cy="100" rx="50" ry="0.1"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: that's cool but, the process is different from what I expected.